# Cpanel Website Redirection using Wildcard

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

I'm having a scenario
which I cant figure out.
I want to change my domain name 
from .Biz to .Com

My scenario.

1. My main domain in my hosting account is example.Biz
2. My parked domain under aliases example.Com
3. I need to redirect with Wilcard all my example.Biz to example.Com
4. Why wildcard, because whenever people click my previous link on Google Search example.Biz/page1 it must redirect to example.Com/page1
5. The CMS i am using for example.Biz is WordPress

Hope you guys can help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create (or edit) the .htaccess file in the web root folder of example.Biz and place the following code in there:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)example\.Biz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Edit: While posting the answer above, I had assumed that you have replicated the entire site at the destination domain (example.com). If not, you need to do that (and then, the .htaccess re-directs should work).

In case you need a way to perform the replication, you can do it easily with the [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: Just curious, do i have to change inside Wordpress, to the new URL which is example.COM

Comment: Oh ok, that means i need to get another hosting and setup the site there, now i got it. I will have to try by next week